# How can I make my irssi look like that?

Tags: irssi

I try to edit my theme and config file but I can't figure out how can I make my irssi look like that:

[image: The Fifth Estate]

I'm stuck, I have no idea how to edit the structure if it's even possible at all.

Comment: To confirm, you're only asking about irssi and not `top` or the editor or whichever terminal multiplexer that's being used there?

Comment: Yes. I looked online and apparently they used Awesome as a windows manager; I know they removed the command column from htop and I have no idea how they did it since it's not supposed to be removable. And what is interesting is the borders from irssi, the editor and htop who is basically exactly like Midnight Commander borders, with the little [^]».